# Vlookup search in a comma separated field

Tags: excel

Excel worksheet with 2 columns.

Cell `A1` has values like `111,222-225,333` then cell `A2` almost same format data like `010,011,444-499`.

How can we lookup a value, say 333 and output corresponding value on adjacent column --(in column B or C etc)?

Vlookup doesn't seem to be a good choice as the first column value needs to be unique.

Secondly, how could we tackle the same above scenario if the lookup value is in that range (say 224, which is in the range of 222-225)

Comment: You need a helper column for your first scenario. For second scenario `VBA` is best option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what value you want to have, but if you want to have the whole cell u might use:
    =LEFT(A1;FIND("333";A1)+3)
in B1 and simply fill it to the rest of column B.

Answer (score 0):

You could share a worksheet with Googledocs with data people could share.

But in essence you would be doing something like string manipulation on A1, to extract the 333.

```
a1=111,222-225, 333
b1=VALUE(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),3))
c1==VLOOKUP(B1,E1:F2,2,FALSE)   // a
d1==IF(ISNA(C1),"",C1)          // a
e1=333 e2=a
f1=444 f2=b
```

The // a - represents the calculated content of the cell